# Silverlight OOB Installation on Mac with download of latest XAP

Tags: macos, installation, silverlight-oob

I have created an offline installation for an OOB Silverlight application on Mac, following this Guide:
http://sharppdf-sl.sourceforge.net/offlineoob.html

It uses Apples `Package Manager`. Here, you have to install the Silverlight OOB application and then use some of the installed data to create a package.

I was wondering, if it is possible to create an installer that downloads the latest xap while installing, i.e. by specifying an URL where the latest xap can be downloaded.

Has anybody made any experiences with such an approach already or any ideas that could lead me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, my approach now was to include an auto-updater in the silverlight app, then create an install-package with the guide mentioned in the question and leave the updating to the app itself. So, my Mac-Installation will most likely not install the latest xap, but will update it immediately.

As far as I could find out, doing an auto-download of the latest xap during installation would not be possible without coding a custom installer. During the 'standard' way of installing an OOB Silverlight App, there are automatically generated some other files, which have to be included in the package manager. This whole thing as not the way it was intended to be, but it works for now.

I will only update my Installation Package when (or even if) I move to a newer Silverlight version, because I also include Silverlight in my installation package itself.

Long story short: Leave updating to the app itself and create an installation package with the app that can update itself.